# PHP-Serialized to JavaScript-Unserialized

Tags: javascript, php, serialization

1. in PHP: `$value = serialize($randomArray);`
2. The `$value` is available as `{{value}}` by TWIG.
3. In JavaScript: `var value = {{value}};`
4. How to unserialize value in javascript to array?

Comment: `json_encode` and `json_decode` to exchange data with js

Comment: Actually, one doesn't need `json_decode` here.

Comment: But then the " sign is replaced by &quot; :(

Comment: Then use `{{value|raw}}` - but make sure that insides of that value are XSS-safe.

Answer (score 0):

From [Twig's documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/json_encode.html):

## json_encode

The json_encode filter returns the JSON representation of a string:

```
{{ data|json_encode() }}
```

So try `{{ value|json_encode() }}` and see if your array is available to the JavaScript.

**Note**: You may have to unserialize $value before passing it into the `json_encode`. Without trying it myself I don't know exactly what it will spit out. But `json_encode` does a lovely job with PHP array-to-JavaScript array/object.